# A simple way to copy file into osx folder

Tags: macos, installation, osx-elcapitan, pkg-file

it's possible copy 3 file into different folder in mac osx via some kind of system?

Scenario

- one file need to be copied, for example a silverlight app inside
  /Application Folder
- one file need to be copied, inside /Documents
  folder
- another inside /picture folder

What can I use?(pkg, a navite osx app) what is the easiest way?
 I need that this is an user friendly installation (no shell script)

Comment: Are you trying to automate this? Use Automator (Automator.app) or AppleScript (Script Editor.app) (included with all Macs). Is this a one time thing? Use the Finder. None of these? Please clarify.

Comment: i need this this for a large number of user. The scenario is that user need my Silverlight application to reproduce some kind of content..they cannot use finder. It's not user friendly for the customer

Comment: if your file goes to System Protected folders you will need admin password since 10.11. You want click solution -> either .app or pkg. I would go for package